# How to resolve : Failed to deploy the application to Worklight server Connection to IP adress refused)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am new to IBM Worklight Studio , I installed it and trying to deploy my first Hybrid app on Worklight Server . The problem is the server isn't starting and the following message is displayed :

```
[2014-05-16 14:21:58]             Project 'HelloWorldHelloWorldAndroid' was imported. 

[2014-05-16 14:21:58]             Application 'HelloWorld' with all environments build finished.

[2014-05-16 14:21:58]             Deploying application 'HelloWorld' with all environments to Worklight Server... 

[2014-05-16 14:21:59]             Failed to deploy the application to Worklight server: please verify that the Worklight server is started and reachable.Connection to 
- MyIpAdress:10080 failed. (Connection to http://myIpAdress:10080 refused)
```

What Should I do to fix this problem to run my project ?

Comment: In eclipse you have server view. Just check the server tab wether any server currently running in your local machine? Also check `http://myIpAddress:100980` wether you can able to access in brower?

Comment: I don't have any other server running , the server doesn't start so  http://myIpAddress:100980 is not accessible

Comment: Try to clean your server and restart and check again?

Comment: Already did it multiple times . there is a problem in to autorisation to access the server , I even changed my Network connection and my IP still the same error message Connection to http://myIpAdress:10080 refused

Comment: Create a new workspace and copy the project or create new one and deploy it to your server. It is weird but sometimes it is working

Comment: It finally worked , i changed the war file location and specified a relative path in the server proprieties and planned a clean in the next start of the server it worked just Fine :) Thank You Bluewing for you help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to verify the location of the projects's war file in the server's parameters to deploy the project that you are working On . And to to right click on the server and choose clean project on next Startup . It will work

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete your bin folder contents.Clean your project and restart the server.

Deploy your application again.